# java how retrieve data from database

Tags: java, sql-server, object, jdbc, return

I have code

```
public static String getData(String query) {
        String output = "";
        try {
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1234;databaseName=123;user=123;password=123";
            Connection con = null;
            Statement stmt = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
                String SQL = "select smth from tableName where smth";
                stmt = con.createStatement();
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    output =  (String) rs.getObject(1);
                }
                rs.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            return "ERROR while retrieving data: " + e.getMessage();
        }
        return output;
    }
```

It works if value is string. But if it integer? Or boolean? How to modify this method so it would be universal, no  matter what type data I get I still return it as string?

Comment: use rs.getInt(0) if it throws exception then rs.getString(0) and so on.... basically you would be knowing the data type in database....

Comment: You can't actually write an accurate generic retrieval mechanism without getting the column type. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First retreive the result in ResultSet rs,
then you can write the code like below.

You can check the instance of the object and than assign the value.

---

```
String str;

Object obj = (Object)rs.getObject(1);

if(obj instanceof String){
   //do you work here for string like below
     str=(String)obj;
}
else if (obj instanceof Integer){
   //do your work for Integer
}
```

// same you can do for other types

---

Answer (score 2):

in this line

```
output =  (String) rs.getObject(1);
```

if **string** then use

```
output =   rs.getString(1);
```

if **int**

```
output =   rs.getInt(1);
```

click [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) for more info

Answer (score 1):

You can't accurately do that without using [ResultSetMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) class to get the column type.

Get the column data according to the type of the column.

Comment: Downvoter, this is the only reliable way to handle any JDBC data type. Everything else will eventually fail at run-time depending on the query.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the value from the resultset presuming that it is always a String and trying to typecast the Object instance. You should make use of the retrieve methods based on the type. Most of the cases, we will be knowing the datatype of the column values from which we retried the data. You can write the program based on the column's type. that's why ResultSet API has a method for each datatype.

```
For String

rs.getString(1);

For Int

rs.getInt(1)
```

Please read the documentation of [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
 while (rs.next()) 
 {
       String[] data;
       data = new String[100];
       data[i] = rs.getString("smth");
       i = i + 1;

  }
```

Try this you got your data in array.. use array instead of object.

Answer (score 0):

what about toString()?

```
while (rs.next()) {
  output = rs.getObject(1).toString();
}
```